# PDF stamps javascript, how to find the stamp instance name?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfstamper

While inserting a pdf stamp I have a script that will retrieve the AP identification of the source stamp.

This is easily done by using `event.source.stampName.`

But what about the name of the stamp instance that is being inserted? I need to identify him in order to change its properties, and not the dynamic text fields only. Is that a possibility?

I searched some alternatives such as:

```
console.println(event.source.stampName);
console.println(event.source.Name);
console.println(event.source.stampAP);
console.println(event.source.AP);
console.println(event.source.stampcreationDate);
console.println(event.source.creationDate);
console.println(event.source.value);
console.println(event.source.documentFileName);
console.println(event.source.source.stampName);
console.println(event.source.source.Name);
console.println(event.source.source.stampAP);
console.println(event.source.source.AP);
console.println(event.source.source.stampcreationDate);
console.println(event.source.source.creationDate);
console.println(event.source.source.value);
console.println(event.source.source.documentFileName);
```

But there isn't really a list of all the properties on the Javascript API, and I'm not sure if this is a possibility even.

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, point 3 is what you're looking for (with PDF-XChange anyway):
https://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/543-Advanced-Dynamic-Stamp-Creation

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the name of the stamp when you stamp it, e.g. change the following property to something like "#MyStampName" instead of "#T2CKw07Lo6sr42d6F3ao#0"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnGc6.png

If so I don't think this is possible - it stamps with the name it was created with. Though I agree with your sentiment that it would be a lot easier to know for sure if there were better availability of the Javascript API properties/attributes...